# prop handlers not working consistently?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a RN app and I'm running into an issue where I try to change the state of a component due to an event that happens in a child component and I'm getting inconsistent results.

```
var app = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <MainLogin onLogin={this.onLogin} />
    );
  },
  onLogin: function() {
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: true});
  }
});

class MainLogin extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Login changeSomething={this.changeSomething} onLogin={this.props.onLogin}/>
    );
  }

  changeSomething() {
    this.setState({something: true});
  }
}

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  loginPressed() {
    this.props.onLogin(); //This works
  }

  changeSomething() {
    this.props.changeSomething(); //This doesn't work
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Button onPress={this.changeSomething.bind(this)}>Change Something</Button>
        <Button onPress={this.loginPressed.bind(this)}>Login</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The onLogin function runs perfectly and is able to set the state of the Grandparent component, whereas the changeSomething function fails (this.setState is not a function).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Smells like binding issue.. try: `changeSomething={this.changeSomething.bind(this)}`

Comment: Well that did the trick instantly. Thank you. Do you know why this would be an issue on one and not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind component methods in ES6 Classes.`React.createClass` automatically doing that, but your second and third components are subclassed with ES6 classes. Here is an [explanation](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding) about that in the official website.

Comment: Ahh okay. That explains it. Thanks.